# A microservice relay between docker container bash and final user

Tags: node.js, bash, docker, http, express

**TL;DR: *how to attach a docker container bash to a node.js stream?***

I need to implement a relay between a docker container bash and the final user. The app is a remote compile/run for c/cpp, Python and JS. Some references ([repl.it](https://repl.it), [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/)). To accomplish that my plan it's to:

1. Instantiate a Ubuntu docker container with the requirements for
   compiling and running the user code.
2. Prompt some bash commands for compiling/running the user code.
3. And finally, output the resulting from the bash console to the user.

I've found some repo's with interesting code they are: [compilebox](https://github.com/remoteinterview/compilebox), [dockerrode](https://github.com/apocas/dockerode) and [docker-api](https://github.com/AgustinCB/docker-api).

The 1st, do the task using containers and some promise/async black magic to compile, pipe out to a file and send to the user through HTTP (get/post). My problem with this one is because I need to establish a shell-like environment for my user. My goal is to bring a bash window over the browser.

The 2nd and 3rd implements API based on the official [HTTP docker engine API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.24/) (I took the v1.24 because this one has an overview for layman's like me). Both have examples of some sort of IO Stream between two entities. Like this, the [duplexstream](https://github.com/apocas/dockerode/blob/master/examples/duplexstreams.js), but because of some mistake of implementation, the IO doesn't work properly ([Issue#455](https://github.com/apocas/dockerode/issues/455)).

So my problem is: how to attach a docker container bash to a node.js stream? So when it's done, everything that the user types in the app on the browser it's sent via HTTP to the bash container and the output is sent back as well.